# Make a richtextbox open from file in a set location

Tags: vb.net

I need to have a richtextbox (rtbUsers) load up a .txt or .rtf (Whatever is easiest) on either form loadup or when a button is pressed (btnLoad) from: C:\ProgramData\Project\test.txt

The only code I have found is for the openfile dialogue, but I need it from a set location. So I am asking if anyone could please give me the code that I need. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call the LoadFile method:

```
richTextBox1.LoadFile("mypathandfile.rtf")
```

For a text file, there is an overload you can use:

```
richTextBox1.LoadFile("mypathandfile.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
```

Comment: Do you know how to open a .txt file? I have tried with Notepad++ to save a .rtf file but it doesn't seem to work when testing the application

Comment: @user1832160 Updated post.  I'm not familiar with Notepad++, but I doubt that it has anything to do with the rtf format.

Comment: I dunno, I think its just the way its saving. I saved it as test.rtf but made a Rich textbox document. Which for some reason vb wont open. Thanks again